# Going Blind, Group or Ring?

Tags: signature, protocol-design, blind-signature

I have several problems approaching the following problem:
Let's assume that we have Alice, Bob and Cathy. Alice wants to present a message to Cathy, showing her that someone else has signed it (Bob), but **without disclosing** Bob's identity. She needs to show that the signature does **not** belong to her.

If we use *blind signatures*. then Alice could be the one who signed it, so we cannot be sure that it was signed from someone else.

By using *group signatures*, more or less we have the same problem, sure there's the group manager who could certify that, but we break the anonymity...

With *ring signatures*, we have the needed anonymity, Bob presents a message having himself along with others, however, if you want to make it efficient, the ring has to be quite small.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Basically, Alice would have to prove that she does NOT know the secret key used for signing. And unless I'm missing something, that should be impossible, because the instance of Alice that knows the key can always simulate an instance of Alice that has less knowledge.

Comment: simple: just have Alice _not_ be part of the (signature) group. $\;$

Comment: **To Maeher:** If you're thinking with blinding, then yes that's the loophole that I see.

**To Ricky** Not having Alice in the signature group would mean that if you have *n* use users, then you need to generate *n* groups, which for large number of users is not practical, as you might have users joining and leaving.

Comment: How about a [zero-knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness-indistinguishable_proof) a[rgument of knowledge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge) of a signing key for one verification key and a signature for a different verification key? $\;$

Comment: *To Ricky:* Your approach sounds **very** good. I hadn't thought of it this way... The only problem that I see now is how to keep Alice from not having multiple keys... Group and ring signatures were providing me this feature... But I believe your approach is closer to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem could be addressed by including an identity in the keys and replacing "different verification key" with "verification key for a different identity". $\:$ Additionally, I now realize that the protocol would need to be [concurrent zero-knowledge](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rafael/papers/easyCZK.pdf). $\:$ (Although I would normally recommend replacing stage 2 of that paper's protocol with something that has a ppt knowledge extractor, such a modification is not necessary in this case.) $\;\;\;$

Comment: I still don't see how Alice would prove that she does NOT know the secret key. There is nothing stopping Alice from knowing a key for a different identity.

Comment: In general, this is pretty much impossible if you allow Alice to have multiple keys: Alice knows the protocol for an honest party, and she could just run that protocol with herself. Even if Alice has just a single key, you need additional restrictions, because in standard zero knowledge you can't even prove a simple statement like $a \neq b$.

Comment: @Maeher : $\:$ The fact that the problem would otherwise become provably impossible to solve is what stops Alice from knowing a key for a different identity. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: If Alice has access to other keys, then bad luck... Group/ring signatures can counter the problem, groups since you have a "registration service" and ring based since you append who could have signed it.
I'm trying to figure how Ricky's proposal could work, given that I cannot embed Bob's identity since it will disclose his identity.

Comment: I thought it was just that _Carol_ cannot learn Bob's identity. $\:$ If you cannot embed Bob's identity (which is a stronger restriction), then the only thing I can think of is to assume that during setup, each allowed party can broadcast a (list of) signature verification key(s) in a way that guarantees that only allowed parties can broadcast and that even those parties can only broadcast once. $\;\;\;$

Comment: Sorry for my writing. Your original assumption is correct: It is *Carol* who must not learn *Bob's* identity.

Comment: In that case, you can use [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure) with an explicit list of [root signature verification keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate). $\:$ (You would pretty much need to reveal an upper bound on the length of the two [certificate chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate), and each party's work would need to scale linearly in that bound, although you could make those parts trivial by having each non-root signed directly by a root.) $\;\;\;$